# Can a Spring Batch job bean be lazily initialized?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, lazy-initialization

In Spring, beans can be configured to be lazily initialized. Spring Batch jobs are also (Spring-managed) beans. That is, when I configure something like

```
<sb:job id="dummyJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <sb:step id="dummyStep">
        <sb:tasklet ref="dummyTasklet" />
    </sb:step>
</sb:job>
```

I actually configure a new (`Job`-typed) bean inside the Spring container.

My issue is I really want my `Job` beans to be lazily initialized. As they are regular Spring-managed beans, I'd expect I can instruct the Spring context to make them lazy. This is because I have a large number of beans and there are many cases in which, during one execution of my Spring-based application, I only run one job.

But there's no `lazy-init` property I can set on my `<sb:job... \>` configuration. Is there any way I can force lazy initialization? If I configure my `<beans\>` root with `default-lazy-init="true"`, will this also apply to the `Job` beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Configure your job manually.  This would allow you to use the regular lazy-init attributes Spring exposes.
2. Use the JobScope now available in Spring Batch 3.  Spring Batch 3 will be available soon, but the JobScope was available in the last milestone.

Comment: 1. You mean configure it as a regular `<bean>` whose class would be one of the `Job` implementers? Won't this approach lose some kind of behind the scenes work that the Spring Batch framework performs when configuring jobs the "straight" way? 2. Is there any documentation on this? I wasn't able to find something relevant. Is the job scope applicable only for tasklets, readers, processors and writers? Or is it also applicable for job beans? I'd need the latter.

Comment: 1.  Yes, that's what I mean.  Keep in mind, the namespace just does the work for you…the work is still being done and there's nothing stopping you from doing it yourself.
2.  Good point.  There isn't a way to set a job to job scope in the namespace.  Just other beans.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on [Michael Minella's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618059/michael-minella) answer.
I had a similar requirement to lazy initialize the job repository.
I am working with Spring Batch 2.1.9.
The following is working for me.

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
     class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
     lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jobDataSource"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="jobTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Note one pitfall I had run into: **do not** set the databaseType i.e. **avoid** the following:

```
<property name="databaseType" value="SQLSERVER"/>
```

This is bad because it disable the auto-discovery of the database type and breaked my JUnits that works on H2.